# NLP algorithms to handle keyword observation

Tags: text-mining, natural-language

I have a document retrieval question that concerns collection of keywords. Some keywords occur as 1 word while some occur as multiple words. How do I penalize such documents?

So, let's say I have a library of books and am working on a search engine. When a user searches for `cookbook` with reference to food, how do I not show titles containing `cookbook` in computing? In other words, how do I decrease the score for say `Python cookbook` or `Java cookbook`?

I've tried using bigrams but the results get sparse very quickly. Is there a way to assign such words? Cosine similarity and TF/IDF also might not do the trick very well.